# Implementing chat feature in android

Tags: android

I want to implement chat feature in my android application,in this feature one user should be able to chat more than one person at a time also he can send smileys to other person.

I would like to know that how can I implement this feature,if you have done this or you know better way kindly share it with me.

Comment: Did you try to read some tutorials, docs, goggle some information, before asking this question? Just can't imagine an answer to your question, please make it more specific.

Comment: This feature is new to me,yes I am searching for this topic, I read that I can use Xmpp(jabber) for this purpose and i am going to that direction,i want to know if any official or 3rd party client is available for that?Or which will be good/best way for implementing this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ListView has a feature that helps make this task less painful. It is called the transcript mode:

```
 android:transcriptMode
```

Here is a [video presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=1928s) on this.

The sdk samples itself has a [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) application which you can use as a reference.

Comment: ListView? I am not asking any problem related to listview although thanx for your posting,and do you really think that bluetooth chat will be suitable for these kind of functionality,I do not have that much of idea related to this, so kindly share your knowledge with me.

Comment: The question you asked is very generic, so I the answer that I've given is how to do the UI bit. BTChat is only for your *reference*. As for things like [smileys](http://dipakkeshariyainandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-add-smileyemojis-in-edittext.html), [chat protocol](http://code.google.com/p/androidchat/), that is something you can customize and decide yourself.

Comment: Thnx I will definately check it now.

Comment: @Reno did you miss android:StackFromBottom ?